# Docker Desktop with WSL2 Unable to Start

Tags: docker, docker-desktop

All of a sudden my working Docker and WSL2 stopped working. I now get the following:

```
$ docker ps
Error response from daemon: dial unix /mnt/wsl/docker-desktop/shared-sockets/guest-services/docker.sock: connect: no such file or directory
```

**Note:** Docker is working and available via Windows.

I've tried the following, without any luck:

- Reinstalling Docker Desktop.
- Reinstalling Docker in WSL.
- Creating the .sock file manually.

**Versions**

- Docker Desktop version: 2.3.0.3 (45519)
- WSL2 with Ubuntu 18.04

```
PS C:\Users\ms> wsl -l -v
  NAME                   STATE           VERSION
* Ubuntu-18.04           Running         2
  docker-desktop-data    Running         2
  docker-desktop         Running         2
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: same problem, worked for a few hours and stopped, restart didn't help

Comment: odd. let me know if you find a fix. Im still looking into it.

Comment: let me know if this helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66026771/my-docker-is-failing-to-launch-on-my-windows-10-pro/66036200#66036200

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After trying multiple things, repair of Ubuntu, a reset of Ubunutu. What worked for me was to:

- uninstall Ubuntu (after backing up my files)
- uninstall Docker Desktop
- reinstall the latest version of Ubuntu 20.20
- reinstall Docker Desktop

Answer (score 9):

No need to install docker desktop, it only generates problems and makes things slower in windows. If you install Docker this way you will never ever again run into that problem:

```
# INSTALL DOCKER PACKAGE
sudo -E apt update && sudo apt upgrade -y
sudo -E apt-get -qq install docker.io -y
# DOCKER DAEMON STARTUP (Substitute .bashrc for .zshrc or any other shell you use)
rcfile=~/.bashrc
echo '# Start Docker daemon automatically when logging in if not running.' >> $rcfile
echo 'RUNNING=`ps aux | grep dockerd | grep -v grep`' >> $rcfile
echo 'if [ -z "$RUNNING" ]; then' >> $rcfile
echo '    sudo dockerd > /dev/null 2>&1 &' >> $rcfile
echo '    disown' >> $rcfile
echo 'fi' >> $rcfile
# ENABLE CURRENT USER AS SUDO FOR DOCKER
echo $USER' ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: /usr/bin/dockerd' | sudo EDITOR='tee -a' visudo
sudo usermod -aG docker $USER
# REBOOT VM MACHINE
wsl.exe --shutdown
```

After installation ends, open a new Ubuntu terminal and it will be ready to rock from now on. You can run any docker image such as:

```
docker run hello-world
```

or

```
docker run -it ubuntu
```

Comment: best answer thank you!!! the desktop overhead was killing me!

Answer (score 1):

I know this may sounds REALLY dumb but have you restarted your computer? I had a similar issue and when I restarted my computer, it worked.

Comment: Yep, multiple times

Answer (score 0):

Try turning off all firewalls on Windows, Then quit docker Desktop and open it again

or

open powershell and run `New-NetFirewallRule -DisplayName "WSL" -Direction Inbound  -InterfaceAlias "vEthernet (WSL)"  -Action Allow`, from: https://visualgdb.com/documentation/wsl2/

or

[image]

Answer (score -1):

I found (in powershell)
wsl --list --verbose

docker-desktop-data  stopped

The reason was that docker-desktop decided to use windows containers. I don't know why.

Comment: And what is the solution to fix it?

Answer (score -1):

If you use Windows, try these two commands in cmd:

`sfc /scannow`
`DISM /Online /Cleanup-Image /RestoreHealth`

After these two commands restart your computer.

Comment: If you can add platform/or/system arch. that will help more.