# My Docker is failing to launch on my Windows 10 Pro

Tags: docker, crash-reports, hyper-v, bios, uefi

I have had some problems with setting up Docker on my Windows 10 pro PC. I get this crash report when I try to open it up:

[Crash Report screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uwkDZ.png)

This is the text that is inside of the box:

```
System.InvalidOperationException:
Failed to deploy distro docker-desktop to C:\Users\Imogen\AppData\Local\Docker\wsl\distro: exit code: -1
 stdout: Access is denied.


 stderr: 
   at Docker.ApiServices.WSL2.WslShortLivedCommandResult.LogAndThrowIfUnexpectedExitCode(String prefix, ILogger log, Int32 expectedExitCode) in C:\workspaces\PR-15138\src\github.com\docker\pinata\win\src\Docker.ApiServices\WSL2\WslCommand.cs:line 146
   at Docker.Engines.WSL2.WSL2Provisioning.<DeployDistroAsync>d__17.MoveNext() in C:\workspaces\PR-15138\src\github.com\docker\pinata\win\src\Docker.Desktop\Engines\WSL2\WSL2Provisioning.cs:line 169
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Docker.Engines.WSL2.WSL2Provisioning.<ProvisionAsync>d__8.MoveNext() in C:\workspaces\PR-15138\src\github.com\docker\pinata\win\src\Docker.Desktop\Engines\WSL2\WSL2Provisioning.cs:line 78
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Docker.Engines.WSL2.LinuxWSL2Engine.<DoStartAsync>d__25.MoveNext() in C:\workspaces\PR-15138\src\github.com\docker\pinata\win\src\Docker.Desktop\Engines\WSL2\LinuxWSL2Engine.cs:line 99
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Docker.ApiServices.StateMachines.TaskExtensions.<WrapAsyncInCancellationException>d__0.MoveNext() in C:\workspaces\PR-15138\src\github.com\docker\pinata\win\src\Docker.ApiServices\StateMachines\TaskExtensions.cs:line 29
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Docker.ApiServices.StateMachines.StartTransition.<DoRunAsync>d__5.MoveNext() in C:\workspaces\PR-15138\src\github.com\docker\pinata\win\src\Docker.ApiServices\StateMachines\StartTransition.cs:line 67
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at Docker.ApiServices.StateMachines.StartTransition.<DoRunAsync>d__5.MoveNext() in C:\workspaces\PR-15138\src\github.com\docker\pinata\win\src\Docker.ApiServices\StateMachines\StartTransition.cs:line 92
```

I have checked my visualization settings and it is enabled. My BIOS is legacy, not sure if UEFI Firmware settings are needed for Docker. My Hyper-V is also enabled in Windows Features. I have also been accessing docker with an authorized cmd. Any advice or suggestions will be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

This is happening because there is an incompatibility between WSL2 and Docker.

If you run `wsl -l -v` I'm quite sure you will see this:

[image]

As you can see the **VERSION** for Debian/Ubuntu/kali-linux is set to 2.

But also docker-desktop is using version 2.

My solution was to

1. open the Start menu and uninstall Debian/Ubuntu/kali-linux

[image]

2. Uninstall Docker
3. Go to Control Panel > Programs > Programs and Features and disable Windows Subsystem for Linux

[image]

4. Now reboot your machine.
5. Log back in, enable once again Windows Subsystem for Linux and reinstall Debian/Ubuntu/kali-linux
6. Now install Docker again but this time at this step untick "Install required Windows components for WSL 2"

[image]

..I know this is not a good news but this is how I fixed it.

Downgrading WSL2 to WSL1 won't help.

Comment: thanks for this detailed sugguestion! sadly it didnt work for me :( but hopefully it will help someone else's problem :)

Comment: Did you have WSL installed in the first place? @Imo

Comment: Yes I do but for some reason it did not ask me to give it elevated privilege's. I just read that when you download it you need to do this but it just goes straight to 'finish' when I download it. I then get this error message when I try to run Ubuntu: Installing, this may take a few minutes...
WslRegisterDistribution failed with error: 0x80070005
Error: 0x80070005 Access is denied.

Comment: Hey just want to let you know that it is now working for me - i just forced it to work with hyperv instead of wsl2 :)

Comment: Didn't know you could do that. Glad to hear you fixed it. We both learnt something

Answer (score 0):

Docker Desktop and Docker Engine never worked for me on Windows 10, it is really unstable. Luckily, you can run Docker solely on your WSL 2 Linux Distro which gives a much more peace of mind. If interested to make docker run perfectly on Windows, install WSL 2 and choose any distro(Ubuntu for my case), then follow [this](https://dev.to/bowmanjd/install-docker-on-windows-wsl-without-docker-desktop-34m9) article to set up Docker.